# Restricting Inappropriate Videos when Uploading to App

Tags: android, iphone, video, upload

I am creating an app for both iOS and Android. The app allows users to create a profile and upload short videos.

My question is, besides the manual revision of videos, how can I prevent uploads that contain nudity or anything that would usually be considered inappropriate?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about recognizing nude images, then I'm very certain that you're out of luck. I don't think that you'll find anyt....wait a minute. I can't actually believe it.

I just went and looked for one to make sure that I was correct in saying that there is no nudity detecting API and voila! I found this:

https://www.mashape.com/rohan/nudity-detection-service#!documentation

Looks like that may be what you need. But in general, nudity detection is...not very easy to say the least. I don't think there is a simple algorithm you could implement. Your best bet is either to use that link that I just gave you, or create a system like YouTube has where offenses are punished fairly severely - things like copyright infringement and nudity result in a ban after just 3 times no questions asked.

I hope that helped. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Alex K's answer, there are many nudity detection APIs available on Mashape:

https://www.mashape.com/explore?query=nudity

https://www.mashape.com/explore?query=porn

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few APIs now available on the Mashape API marketplace for the [detection of nudity in images](https://market.mashape.com/explore?query=nudity), some still relying on skin tone detection (which has a high % of false positives) as well as newer more complex methods that deliver significantly more accurate results without dependence on skin tone such as [Nude Detect](https://market.mashape.com/netspark/nude-detect).